# Remove <a href> that is wrapped around the text inside an LI without removing the LI text

Tags: jquery

How can I remove the `<a href>` that is wrapped around the text of this `<li>` ?

So currently we have:

```
<li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
```

What I want is

```
<li>Text</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.contents().unwrap();
```

is what i needed! ;)